# Extraer correos dentro de una cadena de texto

Tags: c#, regex

Necesito obtener el listado de correos de una cadena de texto. He tratado varias formas y nada resulta. Si alguien de ustedes me podría ayudar, se lo agradecería mucho.

Acá esta mi código:

```
string patern = @"\[A-Za-z]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\";
string inputText = @"Test1 <test1@cariola.cl>, "'Carlos , Tapia'" <ctapia@gmail.com>, Test2 <test2@cariola.cl>"

var matches = Regex.Matches(inputText, patern);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Debug.Print(" {0}", m.Value);
}
```

La salida serÍa:

> test1@cariola.cl
>
> ctapia@gmail.com
>
> test2@cariola.com

Cualquier aporte sería genial.

Comment: por curiosidad, todos los correos estarán dentro de "<" y ">" ?

Comment: El error puntual en tu expresión es que estás escapando el `[` y las comillas de cierre. No deberías. Con `@"[A-Za-z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+"` se obtienen las 3 direcciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el siguiente código podrás sacar todos los correos de tu cadena:

```
const string MatchEmailPattern = @"(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
   + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
     + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
   + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})";
    Regex rx = new Regex(MatchEmailPattern,  RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    string text = @"Texto con los correos";
    MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
    // Número de coincidencias
    int noOfMatches = matches.Count;
    // Por cada resultado
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        //Impresión de los correos
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Funciona perfecto!!!

Answer (score 3):

El principal problema con tu código es que te sobran las barras inicial y final de la expresión regular.

Además deberías utilizar una expresión regular que contemple todos los casos.

Puedes encontrar en internet muchos ejemplos de expresiones regulares para validar e-mails.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo que te funcionará con una expresión un poco más completa que la tuya:

```
string patern = @"\w+@\w+\.\w+";
string inputText =
    @"Test1 <test1@cariola.cl>, 'Carlos , Tapia' <ctapia@gmail.com>, Test2 <test2@cariola.cl>";

var matches = Regex.Matches(inputText, patern);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Debug.Print(" {0}", m.Value);
}
```

Aún así no cubre muchos casos. La he dejado así por simplificar la respuesta.

Comment: Vale aclarar que `\w` es lo mismo que `[A-Za-z0-9_]` más algunos caracteres (acentuados y demás) considerados como letras según la referencia cultural ([`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx))